# AWS IAM not allowing PutObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is what I did:

1) Added the following policy to a IAM user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ] }
```

2) I signed in as that user using the aws-cli

3) Ran the following command:

```
aws s3 sync ./dist s3://bucket-name/ --delete
```

I get a bunch of this:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation:
>   Access Denied

The strange thing is that this works fine:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name
```

which means that my policy is working at some level...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I figured this out. The policy needs to be:

```
[
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ] 
  }
]
```

note the difference in resources. Basically, the bucket itself is considered a different resource from the objects inside it.

Comment: You can also put the resources in a list within the same statement, so "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::bucket" , "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*" ]